# CSS - vertically center a div on a image

Tags: html, css

I have the following html:

```
  <div class='container'>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400" />
    <div class='button-left'><</div>
  </div>
```

What I would like to achieve is for `.button-left` to always be in the center of the image, no matter the image size, but instead the div gets positioned according to my `html` element.

This is my css:

```
.container img {
  position: relative;
}
.button-left {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

Shouldn't the `.button-left` div position according to the relative positioned image?

JsBin in case you want to try out a live demo:
https://jsbin.com/cuwaguyiza/edit?html,css,output

Comment: Yes, only vertically. Horizontaly I would like it to stay where it is :)

Comment: `.container {display: flex; align-items: center;}` & delete u css.

Comment: the .button-left will be absolutely positioned to his parent tag in your case .container so you have to modify your css rules

Comment: just modify .container img {
  position: relative;
} to .container {
  position: relative;
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set `position: relative` to the container and not to the image.
Also I suggest translating the button up, so it is perfectly centered.

```
.container {
    position: relative;
}

.button-left {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `transform: translateY(-50%);` alongside `top: 50%`?

Comment: Because the center point of and element is in the top left corner and not in the center of it. Therefore you have to subtract half the height of the element from `position: top`.
Otherwise the element is not aligned in the center but offset by the elements height downwards

Answer (score 1):

Dont use `position` when no need it.

1. Flexbox.

   ```css
   .container {
     display: flex;
     align-items: center;
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <div class='container'>
     <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400">
     <div class='button-left'>Lorem</div>
   </div>
   ```
2. Line-height (if u text is single-line)

```css
.container img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.button-left {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400"><!-- dont delete this comment
--><div class='button-left'>Lorem</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    .container img {
    position: relative;
}
.button-left {
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background-color: red;

}
```

OR

```
.container img {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```